# what is the regex pattern for the string '<3' and ':)'?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

what is the regex pattern for the string

> <3

and

> :)

I have tried `/<\s*3/g` `/<\d*3/g` `/<\.*3/g` for <3 but its not working.
it is matching in online regex editor but not working on my system.

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/<\s*3/g, '<img src="./img/heart-red.png" alt=""/> ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/&lt;3/g` and `/(?:<|&lt;)3/g`, It should work.